# alternate class to each LI foreach

Tags: php, css, class, html-lists

I am trying to give an alternate class to each LI foreach.

i.e.

```
<li class="odd">
text
</li>
<li class="even">
text
</li>
<li class="odd">
text
</li>
<li class="even">
text
</li>
```

This is my code:

```
<ul>
 <?php foreach ($this->item->extra_fields as $key=>$extraField): ?>
 <?php if($extraField->value): ?>
  <li class="<?php echo ($key%2) ? "odd" : "even"; ?> type<?php echo ucfirst($extraField->type); ?> group<?php echo $extraField->group; ?>">
Text here
  </li>
 <?php endif; ?>
 <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

Please can anyone help...
Thanks

Comment: Nothing wrong with using tables for _tabular_ data.

Comment: What are the keys ? are they numeric ? or associative ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try :

```
<?php $count = 0; // need to set first value
<?php foreach ($this->item->extra_fields as $key=>$extraField): ?>
   <?php if($extraField->value): ?>
      <li class="<?php echo (++$count % 2) ? "odd" : "even"; ?> type <?php echo ucfirst($extraField->type); ?> group<?php echo $extraField->group; ?>">
         Text here
      </li>
   <?php endif; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

[Link to pre/post increment docs if needed](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.increment.php)

Comment: While you code does work and you will get a +1, it is slightly more complicated/confusing than it needs to be. I would initialise `$count` at `0`, and change the condition to `(++$count % 2)`

Comment: thanks for the reply...

I am getting the following error:

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/skiplan/public_html/modules/mod_k2bnr_content/tmpl/Default/default.php on line 81

Comment: @user991830 what is line 81 ... i havent suggested changing anything within a `foreach` statement !

Answer (score 2):

I would do it that way .. it's key independent and you better see what the li-class will look like.

```
<ul>
 <?php 
    foreach ($this->item->extra_fields as $key=>$extraField) {
       if($extraField->value) {
          $toggle = ($toggle=="odd"?"even":"odd");
          echo '<li class="',$toggle,' type',ucfirst($extraField->type),' group', $extraField->group,'">';
          echo 'Text here';
          echo '</li>';
       }
   } 
  ?>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

jQuery can easily do this if that's an option for you. It's [:odd](http://api.jquery.com/odd-selector/) and [:even](http://api.jquery.com/even-selector/) selectors should do just what you're looking for without too much hassle.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but I humbly present a cleaner solution:

```
<ul>
    <?php
        $odd = true;
        foreach ( $this->item->extra_fields as $key => $extraField ) {
            
            // Output template.
            $template = '<li class="%1$s">%2$s</li>';

            // Create our classes.
            $classes = [
                ( $odd ) ? 'odd' : 'even',
                'type' . ucfirst($extraField->type),
                'group' . $extraField->group
            ];

            // Create our class string.
            $class_string = implode( ' ', $classes );

            // Print our content out.
            printf( $template, $class_string, 'Text here' );

            // Flip the classname for next time.
            $odd = ! $odd;
        }
    ?>
</ul>
```

It could of course be cleaner still, by using fewer variables. This is just my style.